# Use function parameter as annotation argument in Scala 2.11.x: annotation argument needs to be a constant

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-2.11

I have a simple helper function that looks like this:

```
  def apply[T: ClassTag](self: T, vid: Long): (T with Serializable ) = {   
    self.asInstanceOf[T @SerialVersionUID(vid) with Serializable]
  }
```

it compiles perfectly in Scala 2.10.x, but in Scala 2.11.x I got the following error:

```
17: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: vid
[ERROR]     self.asInstanceOf[T @SerialVersionUID(vid) with Serializable]
                                                  ^
```

Since its impossible to declare function parameter as final, this confines me to hardcode vid, which is very inefficient. Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

What about (self: T,val vid: Long) at the declaration?

Comment: its a function  :-( Not a class, so far not supported by scala-2.11.7